# Generate Range in used PHP and Skip already

Tags: php, range

I have a total number 47 which start from 0

I need to generate a range for eg: if I need to generate 4 number range I would like to get result 0-4 and for another 5-9

What I want is to generate similar but want exclude already using range eg: 0-4 or 5-9 and in range of 47.

Need to generate 6 count range from 0-47 range.

Available Numbers as below in array

```
 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 [8] => 8 [9] => 9 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 [14] => 14 [15] => 15 [16] => 16 [17] => 17 [18] => 18 [19] => 19 [20] => 20 [21] => 21 [22] => 22 [23] => 23 [24] => 24 [25] => 25 [26] => 26 [27] => 27 [28] => 28 [29] => 29 [30] => 30 [31] => 31 [32] => 32 [33] => 33 [34] => 34 [35] => 35 [36] => 36 [37] => 37 [38] => 38 [39] => 39 [40] => 40 [41] => 41 [42] => 42 [43] => 43 [44] => 44 [45] => 45 [46] => 46 [47] => 47

 print_r($cores);
 $used ='';
 $dediq=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `tblcomputs` WHERE `serverid` = '".$serverid."' AND `status` = 'Active'");
while ($dedi = mysqli_fetch_array($dediq)) {
   if ($dedi['cp'] !='no'){
    $used .= $dedi['cp'];
  }
}
  $required_rangecount ='6';

 //here i'm consufed how to get this done.
```

Comment: I removed numbers used from array with   $used = range(5,9);
        foreach ($cores as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($v, $used)) {
                unset($cores[$k]);
            }
        }

Comment: Now need to get first and last number of range like I get free number to use 9,10,11,12 and I want to get 9-12 in result.

Comment: Run `print_r(array_chunk(range(0, 47), 6))`, does it produce an array that is easier to work with? Unfortunately I really can't tell what your problem is. For any _code changes_, please edit your question instead of posting in comments.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas, After exclude already used value from range I got Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [10] => 10 [11] => 11 [12] => 12 [13] => 13 [14] => 14 [15] => 15 [16] => 16 [17] => 17 [18] => 18 [19] => 19 [20] => 20 [21] => 21 [22] => 22 [23] => 23 [24] => 24 [25] => 25 [26] => 26 [27] => 27 [28] => 28 [29] => 29 [30] => 30 [31] => 31 [32] => 32 [33] => 33 [34] => 34 [35] => 35 [36] => 36 [37] => 37 [38] => 38 [39] => 39 [40] => 40 [41] => 41 [42] => 42 [43] => 43 [44] => 44 [45] => 45 [46] => 46 [47] => 47, How Can we generate continue 6 count number continue

Comment: Now Able to generate with array_chunk($coresd, 6,true) but not getting sequential, I'm getting 0,1,2,3,4,10 on 6 count but I want it should skip not sequential and return 10,11,12,13,14,15

Comment: @Manu please update your post with a clear expected output otherwise it is hard to tell what you want. Please show exactly how you want the array to look like. It is unclear now.

Comment: Able to fix this with while loop, Thank you everyone for kind support.